# Should Paypal IPN be enabled?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

my code must communicate with the paypal system.
I am using a form that takes the user to the payment page of paypal and than I use a page that listen to the Paypal IPN message.

However, do I have to enable something inside the Paypal profile panel? Because inside it there is the tab "IPN", it ask me to provide 1 url, but I have 2 urls (on my website) that listen 2 different IPN messages.

What do I have to do?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two pages to listen to IPN?

Comment: I have something similar to ebay: one is for transactions (buy/sell), and the other is for invoices.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different notification URL per button, by passing a button-specific 'notify_url' with the form variables. Ditto the cancel_url.

Comment: but do I have to enable something in the paypal panel?

Comment: You have to enable IPN, but you don't need to specify a notify URL. The one in the form overrides it.